# React not aware of Redux-Form state change

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

Our app has a page for administrators to make Quotes for our clients.

A Quote consists of one or more "jobs". E.g. If a quote is for installing a fridge, and doing yard work the Quote would consist of the following two jobs:

- Fridge Installation -$xx
- Yard Work - $yy

There is other metadata associated with a job that warrants a whole other form for creating / editing a single job.

Hence the page for creating / editing a single quote consists of two forms:

1. Quote form for handling the currency of the quote, the title of the 
   quote, toggling of jobs, and deleting of jobs
2. Job form (in the shape of a Modal) for handling the title of the job, description of the job and a list of items that break down the work to be done for that job

I have a top-level container component that renders the following 2 Redux-Form components:

```
    {/* IN CONTAINER COMPONENT */}
    <JobModalForm
      onSubmit={this.saveJob}
    />
    <QuoteForm
      initialValues={quote}
      onSubmit={this.updateQuote}
      updateQuote={this.updateQuote}
      deleteQuote={this.deleteQuote}
      publicQuoteUrl={this.props.publicQuoteUrl}
      linkCopied={() => { this.props.snackbarString('link copied!') }}
    />
```

Both of these forms are stored in separate parts of the form state:

```
--form |
       | -- quote
       |
       | -- job
```

However, these two forms have to communicate with each other.

**All is working except for one thing:**

When I update a job (whether pre-existing using `initialValues` or newly-added) for the first time, the update works: If I change the price on a job, the `QuoteForm` will render the new price. This is done through reduxForm's `arraySplice`

```
  // in container component ...
  // onSubmit handler for JobModalForm
  saveJob = (job, dispatch, props) => {

      // if this is an existing job (whether or not it has been created in the db or not)
      // update it
      // else 
      // append the job to the existing quote
      if (job._id || job.fresh) {
         const action = arraySplice('quote', 'jobs', job.index, 1, job)
         dispatch(action)
      } else {
         dispatch(arrayPush('quote', 'jobs', job ))
      }

      dispatch({ type: JobModalActions.TOGGLE_MODAL })
}
```

However, subsequent updates to **ANY** existing Fields within QuoteForm's ArrayField do not trigger a `render` from React. E.g. changing the price on any job after my initial update does not get noticed by React.

*Redux-Form successfully dispatches an action* and *the store's `form` key  does contain the updated fields*.

Curiously enough, creating any number of jobs does work (by way of `arrayPush` as seen above).

I'm totally stumped and need some help on figuring out why form submissions for `JobModalForm` only work for new jobs.

---

### Appendix

Here is an example replicating the issue:
https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KgoQMIyvxdJb7Pvh0eu

#### [Code snippets](https://gist.github.com/gDelgado14/3756ce81e27c39644f9f7b0e4f9bc62b)

Versions of packages:

```
"react-redux": "^4.4.1",
"redux": "^3.3.1",
"redux-form": "^6.5.0",
"redux-form-material-ui": "^4.1.2",
```

#### JobModalForm

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(reduxForm({
  form: 'job',
  enableReinitialize: true
})(JobModal))
```

#### QuoteForm

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(reduxForm({
  form: 'quote'
})(QuoteForm))
```

Comment: This may be a bug. You're a little behind in versions iirc, so update; then use the React Devtools to inspect the props and state for all involved components.

Comment: @w00t I updated the aforementioned packages, `rm -rf node_modules`, installed the entire project dependencies once more and I am still getting this error. Going to try inspecting with React Devtools. Thanks.

Comment: If you made a standalone minimal example then it would be easier for someone to take a look.

Comment: Yeah, what @dpwrussell said. I'm not fully understanding what, exactly, the problem is. I've looked through your code snippets, and don't see any glaringly obvious problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized this is a shallow comparison issue within Redux-Form - not my source.

[Here](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/src/FieldArray.js#L32) is the issue. As you can see, Field Array does shallow comparison without allowing the user to allow for deep comparison.

There's actually a PR within the repo ([link](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/pull/2465)) that resolves this very issue.

Comment: Well, `redux-form` is meant to be used with `redux`, which assumes that all values are shallow-comparable for equality… Are you mutating the job?